# Stucture Map using Configuration Manager in ObjectFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, inversion-of-control

I am using structure map in MVC4 Project and I am trying to use Configuration Manager in ObjectFactory:

```
public static IContainer Initialize() {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                    {

                        x.Scan(scan =>
                                {
                                    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                                });

                        var someConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("someconfiguration") as SomeConfigurationSection;


                    });
        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }
```

I am having and error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. Parser Error Message: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for someconfiguration: This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase.
```

Is it possible that I cannot use Configuration Manager in Object Factory? If not, what is possible way to read web.config for dependency injection purpouses?

P.S.
Without usage of ObjcetFactory, ConfigurationManager is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer to the question by myself.

Structure map is creating file in App_Start and the special class that is initializing the Factory

```
 [assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Web.UI.App_Start.StructuremapMvc), "Start")]
namespace Web.UI.App_Start
```

If just copy/pasted everything that was in Start method to Global.asax and problem was no longer the issue